# Why Nuget package need to be added in the dependent project for execution?

Tags: .net-core, dependencies, nuget, console-application

Created 3 projects in a solution.

A. Class library targeting .NET Standard Library
    Retrieving a database value using **System.Data.SqlClient** which is added via NuGet

B. .NET Core console application : Referencing project A to display the DB value

C. .NET Framework console application : Referencing project A to display the DB value

Project B works fine when running, but Project C gives below runtime error.

[image]

If I add the **System.Data.SqlClient** in Project:C, then it will start working. Is it mandatory to add dependent NuGet packages of project A to project C?

Also I want to know the reason of different behavior between .NET Core and .NET Framework console applications.